# Is it ok to use JSON strings for relations in Oracle database

Tags: json, database, oracle, database-performance

Some time ago I joined a project with Oracle (11.2) database. JSON strings are heavily used in it for relational data:

1. instead of using separate tables for many to many relationships, JSON string are used. For example: let's suppose we have Student and Lecture tables. In our architecture Student table will have "Lectures" column. It will contain JSON array with lecture names (not lecture Ids even, but names). For one to many relations though, other's table ID is used instead of JSON.
2. often whole objects are stored inside JSON columns, instead of separate tables. So for Student you can have i.e. Grades column where you have JSONs like { Grade: 'A', Date: '2015-01-01', Lecture: 'Mathematical Analysis'}
3. objects are retrieved with MicroOrm and those JSONs are parsed in the C# code so JSON strings become lists of simple objects. For each JSON column we have code like this:

`private string _lecturesJson;
    public string LecturesJson
    {
        get { return Lectures.ToJson(); }
        set { _lecturesJson = value; Lectures = value.FromJson<List<string>>(); }
    }
    public List<string> Lectures { get; set; }`

The whole architecture is somehow mixing relational and document database paradigms. I tried to convince the architect that such solution is bad, but he insists such architecture is very nowadays. I agree that there is a lot of going on in document databases world. But this is completely different, isn't it? In my opinion there are at least several reasons why it is bad:

1. searching performance will be disastrous. E.i. calculating average grade for Mathematical Analysis for all students. You have to read/pase all those JSON values.
2. you cannot set up indexes on JSON keys
3. you cannot set up constraints like primary keys or foreign keys on JSON keys - data consistency is threatened. Actually for most of tables there are no primary keys or foreign keys set at all (I mean those one to many tables where data is linked by plain Id),
4. database size is bigger than it needs to be - we are storing names of other objects, which are redundant - what if referenced object name is modified? It seems we have to go through all JSON strings and update those names (as I wrote we use names instead of Ids to link data).

The application itself should be optimised for data querying, since most of the time searching and data exporting is used.

Am I right? Is this totally wrong or maybe there is some trend that I am not aware of? Are there any other reasons why this architecture is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.

You can store clobs/blobs in a relational DB.  This does not mean using a relational DB as a doc store is a trend, more of an anti-pattern

If you need a doc store, try Mongo or OrientDB.

If you need to join data across multiple JSONs this would be horribly inefficient, having the data in fields means you can join on any column.  It also means you need someone who understands data modeling.

If you need to pull that data in JSON, better to make a stored proc, or better yet a REST API that provides the JSON from the tables, you then have the flexibility to provide any other representation without affecting your model.... but from your description it sounds like you don't even need the json.

Answer (score 1):

"The whole architecture is somehow mixing relational and document database paradigms." - yes, you're right.  It's entirely possible to use a relational database in exactly this way.  It makes perfect sense when you only search for and use the JSON in its entirety: all or none.  You key on it using a primary key, not on values inside.

If you do need to search on a limited set of values inside, it's entirely possible to add a few extra columns and index on those.  Your search concerns are easily addressed.

As for database size - unless you're talking about terabytes or petabytes of info, I think this concern is overblown.  You ought to be partitioning your transactional data by date and moving older partition out to a historical database, anyway.  You have another problem if you have multiple years of transactional data in your database.

Comment: Often we have to query database by the contents of the JSONs - in searches mainly.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 12c has native support for JSON, have a look [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/json-support-in-oracle-database-12cr1.php)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use anything but your best practice is that keys should really only be on GUID fields.  In a well normalized database you will typically be joining on those keys.

If you really need to match on the entirety of the document, generate a hash of the document on insert and index that hash.  You can join on the hash and it will be much more efficient.

That said, if you are storing whole JSONs you may want to take a look at mongo, or another document store.

Comment: Hi, it seems that your answer is a little off-topic: the question is not "how", but "is it right to".